# Javascript initialisation and error handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, initialization, standards

I am writing an Angular app, coming from a PHP background. What is the standard approach to initialisation and error handling. For example take my JWT Token factory.

```
app.factory('Token', ['jwt_decode', function(jwt_decode) {

    var token = null, expiry = null, role = null;

    return {

        get: function() {
            return token;
        },

        set: function(value) {

            token = value;

            var data = jwt_decode(token);

            expiry = data.exp;
            role = data.role;

        },

        clear: function()
        {
            // performed on session expiry or logout.
            token = null;
            expiry = null;
            role = null;
        },

        has: function()
        {
            return token !== null;
        },

        getRole: function()
        {
            return role;
        },

        getExpiry: function()
        {
            return expiry;
        }
    };

}]);
```

I have initialised my private variables as null but I have read some blogs which instead suggest I leave them as undefined. If I leave them as undefined should my clean method set these back to undefined or null? If I set them to undefined I believe my has function should then be token !== undefined?

Lastly if say a invalid token was passed e.g. 123 how should this be handled, is it common to throw like I would in PHP? I am yet too see much error handling in JavaScript to know the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null or undefined is a matter of style. Choose one of those and be consistent. The key in js test for falsy or thruthy values. That is your has method could return !!token, so if the token is null or undefined or '' will be false and true otherwise.
It is a good practice to wrap your code in an self invoking anonymous function and make undefined as a parameter because is not a reserve word in js and anyone could assign a value to undefined.

```
(function(angular, $, undefined){

}(angular,jQuery));
```

Exception handling you have try/catch to handle unexpected behavior or you can throw errors (throw 'Unexpected token'). Again you can catch the errors that you throw with try/catch

Comment: Can I ask which of the two methods you employ ?

Comment: I do everything that i just told you :-) May sometimes is better on a function to throw a meaningful error so that you can debug, the try/catch is to prevent your user to see any wierd messages on the console or the ui